# blocking a netty thread temporarily puts netty in very bad state?

Tags: netty

We have a concurrentlinkedqueue that blocks after 100 entries to slow the incoming data down.  It is deeper in the playframework code.  When, we block the netty thread for a bit and then release it, it seems to put netty in some bad state where once released and we are done and no longer blocking the thread, there are reads that are no longer being fired.

basically, the consumers eventually catch up and everything works sort of except a page request ends up returning 14 of 16 js/css/image files or so.  playframework never receives the http requests on 2 of the 16 files.  This only occurs after blocking the netty thread for a short amount of time.

lastly, a stack dump reveals netty to be in a normal state like there are no read requests to fire while play has not received them and chrome is still waiting for those 2 of 16 files to be downloaded.  It is very weird.  When we don't block the netty thread here and there, everything works fine and it never gets into this bad state.

Any ideas?

(we are still debugging the netty source but just curious if anyone has some ideas out there)

thanks,
Dean